# Setting external dependencies in a .Net Core (c#) app

Tags: c#, .net-core

My application will need to use an external command line app at some point. I will then create a process and then call the external executable. The command line tool is available for Unix and Windows systems and I was wondering what is the best way to set the dependencies in my .NET Core app.

Of course, I could write code to download the executable for the current OS where the app is running on in Base directory and then reference it in the app but it seems pretty wasteful as if the user has already install the commandline via `yum` or `apt-get` then it doesn't make sense to re-download the binaries.

Comment: Could it be part of the deployment of the App?

Comment: @FrankNielsen could you please elaborate , i am new with .Net

Answer (score 1):

There can be two ways to solve this problem.

**Check in the installer:**

I would suggest to add check in installer of your .NET Core app, to see if the dependency is present by looking at windows registry (or any similar table depending on OS where you are installing your application).

You can stop installation and ask user to install the dependency first. 
The other option is to download the utility as a part of your installation process and install it.

**Check in the app:**

If you do not want to do this during installation, you can also do this either during app startup or during the startup of your module which needs this external dependency.   You can detect and if it is not available, can show a nice information message to user to download and install it.

The decision will totally depend on the design of your application.